# Incorrect use of あげさせます？

Tags: conjugations, causation, giving-and-receiving

I drafted a sentence practicing **causative form**:

私はフレイザーに筆入れを**あげさせます**。

desired meaning : I made Fraser give me the pencil case.

But when I put this sentence on a correction site someone corrected it to just あげます. I wanted it to be causative (I **made** Fraser do it) so I am unsure whether the person who was correcting misinterpreted the sentence or if I was using the form incorrectly.

Comment: Great question.  I think they misunderstood what you wanted to say.  I'm not sure exactly how to put together what you want to say, but I think you need to use the verb くださる since you're the recipient of the pencil case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あげる, as a verb, would never have 'me' as the indirect object.

I think the verb you're seeking is 譲（ゆず）る
（私は）フレイザーに筆入れを（自分に）譲らせた/譲らせました